# autossh tunnel getting killed after 10 minutes

Tags: autossh

I have an `autossh` tunnel set up over which I am sending something that needs an uninterrupted connection for a couple dozen minutes. However, I noticed that every 10 minutes the SSH tunnel managed by `autossh` is killed and recreated.

This is not due to an inactive connection, as there is active communication happening through that channel.

The command used to set up the tunnel was:

```
autossh -C -f -M 9910 -N -L 6969:127.0.0.1:12345 remoteuser@example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was a clash of the monitoring ports on the remote server. There are multiple servers all autossh-ing to the single central server and two of those "clients" used the same monitoring port (`-M`).

The default interval in which `autossh` tries to communicate over the monitoring channel is 600 seconds, 10 minutes. When `autossh` starts up, it does not verify that it could open the remote monitoring port. Everything will look fine until the time when `autossh` tries to check that the connection is open - and it fails. At that point the SSH tunnel will be forcibly killed and recreated.

A good way to check if this is your case as well is change the default timeout using the `AUTOSSH_POLL` environment variable:

```
AUTOSSH_POLL=10 autossh -C -f -M 9910 -N -L 6969:127.0.0.1:12345 remoteuser@example.com
```

Comment: In my case, it because the my monitor port is below 1000(I used `-M 666`), it cannot open in the remote sever. So every POLL time it will be failed and reconnect. Solution is change monitor port to a higher port: `-M 666` => `-M 6666`.

Comment: monitor port is opened on server or the client?